# How to get a list of my app's tasks and the stack of their Activities?

Tags: android

In order to better understand the relationship between Activities, tasks, the back-stack for each task, and different launchModes I want to write an app with about 7 Activities, running in 3 tasks, where the Activities are launched in different launchModes, and as I'm running I want to display the stacks for each activity and watch them change as I navigate through my app and launch or close different Activities.

How can I get a list of all the Tasks for my current application and then get the Activities on those tasks' stacks?  The [ActivityManager class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) lets me query task info based on what's recent or what's running but how do I query task info just for my current app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A "task" doesn't belong to an app, and an "Application" doesn't belong to a task. A task can have different activities from different applications in it and an application can have activities running in different tasks.

Comment: There is an open-source program that pretty much does this. It is a great tool for trying things out and for understanding how launchModes and Intent flags behave (or don't behave). Look at https://github.com/gnorsilva/Activities-LaunchMode-demo

Comment: One of the things that is lacking in Android is a way to programatically look at the activity stack in a task. There are a lot of applications that would be improved if this was possible. Also, debugging would be easier. Sadly, it isn't possible :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I get a list of all the Tasks for my current application

There is no such concept. Tasks can *contain* activities from an application. To drawn an analogy, no Web site owns the back stack of a browser tab, though a Web site's pages may be in the back stack of a browser tab.

> then get the Activities on those tasks' stacks?

That is not possible, as the activities are not necessarily all from your process.

> The ActivityManager class lets me query task info based on what's recent or what's running but how do I query task info just for my current app?

You don't, strictly speaking.

You can iterate over the running tasks, and you can find those where one of your activities is the `baseActivity` or the `topActivity` based on those `ComponentName` values.

Or, your activities know their task ID, obtained [via `getTaskId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getTaskId%28%29). If you need to, you can find those tasks in the running tasks, matching up the ID values, to find out task-level details about the activity's task.

Comment: OK, finding out which tasks my Activities are running in (via getTaskID, as you suggest) will give me a list of tasks.  Once I have the Task ID, I how can I break down the stack so I can see where my Activities are with respect to the other activities in the stack?

Comment: @user316117: "how can I break down the stack so I can see where my Activities are with respect to the other activities in the stack?" -- I do not believe that this is possible.

Answer (score 7):

If you have access to adb, you can use below command to view all tasks and stacks available.

```
adb shell am stack list
```

Comment: This only get the task name and the top activity of each task.

Answer (score 4):

From sdk version 21 you can now call ActivityManager.getAppTasks() to get tasks belonging to your application.

Answer (score 1):

With the below code you can get task number

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        val activityManager = getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
        val tasks = activityManager.appTasks
        tasks.forEach {
            logApp("it.taskInfo.numActivities:${it.taskInfo.numActivities}")
        }
    }
```