# Where is "Activity Manager State" in Android Studio 3?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, adb, android-studio-3.0

There was a very handy feature for debugging, that was present in Android studio 2.x, but currently is not there in 3.x.

It was a bit hidden in the UI:

[image]

Then it will prompt with detailed activity manager state:

[image]

I know, that I can acquire that output with `adb shell dumpsys activity top`, I'm just curious whether it is possible to get the old functionality back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by [Wojtek Kaliciński](https://twitter.com/wkalic) in a [tweet](https://twitter.com/wkalic/status/923904515442663425):

[image]

A bug is opened [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68382141).

---

### Update

> We apologize if this was inconvenient. The old feature is still available from the terminal tool window by doing **"adb shell dumpsys activity"** and have it in a file. We plan to integrate more of this into the actual UI of the profilers as opposed to a plain txt file out of the command.